# what is the rightclick handler in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers

I used rightclick handler with openlayers2 and now I am upgrading my website to openlayers3 and I cannot find this handler in ol3

Comment: This can help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/contextmenu/ol3-dev/yCgIcbURw9M/cPPJNCMW2PQJ

Answer (score 10):

Just repeating/summarizing some other answers. You can add your own listener on `viewport`:

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener('contextmenu', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    console.info('contextmenu');
});
```

Or use an extension I've written to address this feature - https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-contextmenu - [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ooxs1w5d/).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32246757/4640499.